# How is a leader elected in Hyperledger Fabric PBFT?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In Hyperledger Fabric, the leader is responsible for adding blocks to the blockchain. All the validating nodes elect the leader. But how is this leader elected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Hyperledger Fabric Gossip, see [Leader Election](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/gossip.html) and [Channels](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/channels.html) for a description of how a leader is elected

Comment: It mentions in dynamic leader election that a "leader election procedure" is used. But doesn't mention how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer applies only to Hyperledger Fabric Gossip. Gossip is a decentralized message broadcast mechanism that forwards messages to random peers. It is *not* a consensus algorithm.

As for consensus algorithms, for Hyperledger Sawtooth and all blockchain platforms in general, PBFT or Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance Consensus selects a leader in a round-robin manner.  A new leader is elected only if there is a suspicion that the old leader is no longer available.

For details see the original 1999 paper by Castro and Liskov at http://pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/osdi99.pdf

Comment: If it is the case, why is it said that PBFT is ***Byzantine*** fault tolerant (in addition to Crash fault tolerant), when ***a Byzantine leader can always be "available"***, though it is an attacker node.
***I mean a Byzantine leader can still remain as a leader as long as it is "available".*** Isn't it?
And if it is the case, logically, PBFT does not tolerate Byzantine faults.